# panel data merge for categorical variable

Tags: merge, stata

My data in Stata is in panel form.
countrycode     year
AFG           1990
..            1991
..            1992
..            ..
BAN           1990
..            1991
..            1992

Now I would like merge an Excel file which is consisting income based classification of countries:
countrycode
AFG             Low income
BAN            Low middle income
ANG            Low middle income
IND            Low middle income
BAH            High income

How can I add this to the previous main file ?

I used

```
merge m:m Country using "C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\merge file.dta"
keep if _merge==3
drop _merge
```

But it mixed up the year and destroyed the organization or serial of the year like:
countrycode     year
AFG           1992
..            1990
..            1991
..            ..
BAN           1991
..            1990
..            1992

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info for advice on how to ask a question. The way this is presented prevents you from obtaining the assistance you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In principle this is a 1:m `merge`, not m:m.

The following shows the main idea.

```
* cd to some suitable directory 

* you should already have this dataset 
clear 
input str3 countrycode year 
AFG 1990 
AFG 1991 
AFG 1992
BAN 1990 
BAN 1991 
BAN 1992
end 

save file1 

* again, you should already have this dataset 
clear 

input str3 countrycode str17 status 
AFG "Low income" 
BAN "Low middle income" 
end 

* this is the key 
merge 1:m countrycode using file1 

sort countrycode year

list , sepby(countrycode)

     +---------------------------------------------------+
     | countr~e              status   year        _merge |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  1. |      AFG          Low income   1990   Matched (3) |
  2. |      AFG          Low income   1991   Matched (3) |
  3. |      AFG          Low income   1992   Matched (3) |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  4. |      BAN   Low middle income   1990   Matched (3) |
  5. |      BAN   Low middle income   1991   Matched (3) |
  6. |      BAN   Low middle income   1992   Matched (3) |
     +---------------------------------------------------+
```